# How to encode ¿ to ISO-8859 with WSO2 ESB

Tags: encoding, jms, wso2, wso2-esb

During the evaluation of sample data I discovered the following problem. When the content in the JMS contains the "upside down question mark" `<test>Inverted¿QuestionMark</test>`, the proxy crashes - in fact **hangs and the CPU goes up to 100%**.
Here the code of the proxy to reproduce easily:

Just add `<test>Inverted¿QuestionMark</test>` into a queue named "test_qEncoding" and see how the CPU goes up and the proxy hangs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test_encoding_crash_jms" transports="jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">test_qEncoding</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">myQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/xml;charset="iso-8859-15"</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
    <target>
        <inSequence>        
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="Context" value="Proxy test_encoding_crash_jms called"/>
            </log>
            <log level="full"/>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

When I use a vfs proxy and read as ISO-8859 it works. When I don't specify `;charset="iso-8859-15"`then it works also, but the content is then not in the correct endoding for my output.

**How should I get the message from the JMS when I want to send it then as ISO-8859?**

**Why does the above proxy hangs and blocks the whole WSO2 ESB?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported sometime back [1]. Seems to be an issue existing. Please refer the JIRA for more details. Further if you can reproduce it consistently please mention that so we can raise the priority.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1751